# Why is an empty Model returning to post method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Ok, a similar question has being posted but I'm not seeing an answer that would apply to this scenario or the more likely, I'd fully understand the answer !

Basically I have a get ViewResult and Post ActionResult , the Get returns the correct model but when submitting, the model returns all properties as null ?
Have user similar code in other methods and it works, can anyone see the problem ?
Still learning , so please explain any answer, thanks.

```
         [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult DeleteUser(string username)
    {
        IQueryRunner<User> getUser = new NhQueryRunner<User>();
        User user = getUser.GetQueryResult(new GetNamedEntity<User>(username));

        ViewUserModel model = Mapper.Map<User, ViewUserModel>(user);

        return View("DeleteUser", model);
    }

     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteUser(ViewUserModel model)
    {
     }
```

View

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteUser", "Company", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    Are you sure you want to delete Username - @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Remove User"/>
</fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form submits values from it's inputs. You don't have inputs with names equal to your model properties names, so submitted form data does not contain these values. Other [value providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) (query string, route data, etc) also don't have values corresponding to model properties. So, model binder cannot bind values and you have all properties of your model equal to `null` (which are reference type properties).

You can use @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)` as suggested by @Michael to generate hidden input in your form:

```
<input id="Name" type="hidden" value="username_value" name="Name">
```

Now if you'll check `Request.Form` values collection, it will contain entry with key `Name` and `username_value` value. `FormValueProvider` provides access to this collection to model binder. And property with name `Name` will be bound successfully.

Comment: It's seems like `name` and not `username`

Comment: @YairNevet thanks, just looked on Get method parameter when wrote answer, updated now

Comment: How do I check Request.Form values collection ? I assume I keep my original input tag line too ?

Comment: @mkell it's available in controller action. You don't need to verify it manually - I just pointed that if value will be submitted by form, then it should present in that collection. Binder will look for that value automatically

Comment: Thanks @SergeyBerezovskiy , just so I'm clear , I'm listing my values in the view as @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FirstName) etc.. and adding the input line of code you wrote above ?...I'm doing something wrong, as I'm still getting the same error ?

Comment: @mkell no, you are adding HiddenFor to generate hidden input. Input is rendered for you, you don't need to add it manually.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, this is dragging out, apologies, I'm coming in on another developers project, so I still finding my way,  My view now contains,@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteUser", "Company", FormMethod.Post)) , all the properties of the model (hidden) and the following...<input type="submit" value="Remove User"/>   , if this is correct, the problem must lie elsewhere, as I'm still getting the    "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key" error and I thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an empty model because there are no `input` controls for the properties on the model in the form. Even the `DisplayFor` won't send a value back in the `POST`. I would recommend doing this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property1)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property2)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property3)

...
```

where `Property{n}` are the properties on the model.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm sure thats the solution, however I hit an error before it reaches the post method,"Value cannot be null.Parameter name: key", (there is no "key" listed with the model)I'm gonna have to do a bit more digging, but I would have thought the program would have hit the break point on the post Method immediately after the submit ?..... cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a form input element in your form section so that the browser can post back to the server.  Update your code and add the following property

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteUser", "Company", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    Are you sure you want to delete Username - @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Remove User"/>
</fieldset>
}
```